# Joining two tables with JPA

Tags: jpa, netbeans, eclipselink, named-query

I'm trying to use a `@NamedQuery` to join two tables, `Address` and `Division`.  There are multiple divisions at the same address.  At the moment I have
Division.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="division")
@NamedQuery(name="Division.mailingAddress", query="SELECT d, a from Division d LEFT JOIN d.addresses a")
public class Division implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="division_id")
    private Short divisionId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="division_name")
    private String divisionName;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="address_id")
    private Short addressId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="divisionMailingAddress")
    private List<Address> addresses;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Addresses.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GeneratedType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "address_id")
    private Short addressID;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "mailing_address")
    private String mailingAddress;

    @ManyToOne
    private Division divisionMailingAddress;
}
```

The error I get when I run this is:
`Unknown column 't0.DIVISIONMAILINGADDRESS_division_id' in 'on clause'`

What I'm trying to get is this line that works in MySQL:
`SELECT * FROM (division d join address a on d.address_id = a.address_id);`
Currently the JPA is resolving the named query to:
`SELECT t1."all columns", t0."all columns" from division t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN address t0 ON (t0.DIVISIONMAILINGADDRESS_division_id = t1.division_id)`
What is wrong with what I am doing?  Does the JPA want the join coming from the address vs the division?  How Do I get the call to be made off of `address_id` vs `division_id`?

### UPDATE:

With great assistance here are what the two classes have been changed to accomplish what I had wanted the outcome to be.

Division.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="division")
@NamedQuery(name="Division.mailingAddress", query="SELECT d from Division d LEFT JOIN d.addressesM2O a")
public class Division implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="division_id")
    private Short divisionId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="division_name")
    private String divisionName;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="address_id")
    private Short addressId;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Address.java)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private Address addressesM2O;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Address.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GeneratedType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "address_id")
    private Short addressID;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "mailing_address")
    private String mailingAddress;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="addressesM2O")
    private List<Division> divisionO2M;
}
```

The `@NamedQuery` was changed since `d` and `a` being present made the result list return a list of `Object[]`. Which was the object `Division` and `Address`.  Thus is why `d` was kept and `a` was removed from the `@NamedQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are not mentioning the `@JoinColumn` while mentioning `@ManyToOne` in the Address class , due to which while making the join JPA itself is creating the foreign key *DIVISIONMAILINGADDRESS_division_id*.

Try to mention ManyToOne relationship in Address class as below and let me know if any issue occurs:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Division.class)
@JoinColumn(name= "division_id")//basically the name of the column here should be same as the one mentioned in your database
```

Comment: I have added the `targetEntity` and I still get the error above.  When also adding the `JoinColumn` I get a different error. `Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [address.division_id].  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be read-only.`  How do I go about making the entries read-only?

Comment: In the JoinColumn annotation add updatable =false, insertable =false

Comment: Adding those two quantifiers worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: Other thing I found, which I need to post an update about, was that with the `@ManyToOne` working I don't need to include the `Address` in the `@NamedQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing the `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` to being `@OneToOne` with a `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` in the `address` table. Code update below:
Division.java changed to:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="divisionMailingAddress")
private Address address;
```

Address.java changed to:

```
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Division divisionMailingAddress;
```

Comment: This gives a false positive.  This will try and use the PKID from Address and try and Join on the PKID from Division.  If both use the same PKID then good to go.  Otherwise this will give a false positive.